# Как разрешить всем пользователям завершать задачи?

Tags: битрикс24

Как завершить задачу, если постановщик был другое лицо? Где и как дать права? В задачах права сколько не менял, все равно завершать не дает, можно только под админом, как эту опцию выдать на всех?